# ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to call the `user_id` and `role_id` field from a hash `current_role`. When I try calling `current_role.role_id` or `current_role.user_id`, I get the following error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `role_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_RoleMembership:0x00000103d4fbd0>):
```

If I try to run `current_role.inspect`, I see that both `user_id` and `role_id` are both set. Here is the response from `current_role.inspect`:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<RoleMembership id: 1, user_id: 1, role_id: 2, created_at: "2014-01-27 02:25:25", updated_at: "2014-01-27 02:25:25">]>
```

Why am I unable to call `current_role.role_id` or `current_role.user_id`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `current_role` is an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation` and not `RoleMembership`.

To get the `role_id` of the first `RoleMembership` in the `current_role` relation, use:

```
current_role.first.role_id
```

If you want to make current_role default to the first `RoleMembership`, you should update your `current_role` definition to something like follows:

```
def current_role
  RoleMembership.where(...).first
end
```

With the updated `current_role` definition, you will then be able to use `current_role.role_id` and it will return the expected `role_id`.

Comment: That fixed it! If I was going to include like a limit for only one record, would I not have to include the `first`?

Comment: @evanvee, No, using `limit` is also going to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` but with the limited records.